# Setting up JDBC to check for correct username and password

Tags: java, user-interface, jdbc

Trying to set up a JDBC that checks a database for a matching username and password, and they when the login button is pressed if matching the user is granted access, I've got my current code here, but I'm unsure what is missing when I launch the program it seems like its not checking the database for the correct information.

Updated:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class NewClass extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jtfUsername, jtfPassword;
    private JButton backButton, loginButton;
    private JMenuItem jmiLogin, jmiBack, jmiHelp, jmiAbout;

    NewClass() {
        //create menu bar
        JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();

        //set menu bar to the applet
        setJMenuBar(jmb);

        //add menu "operation" to menu bar
        JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");
        optionsMenu.setMnemonic('O');
        jmb.add(optionsMenu);

        //add menu "help"
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        helpMenu.setMnemonic('H');
        helpMenu.add(jmiAbout = new JMenuItem("About", 'A'));
        jmb.add(helpMenu);

        //add menu items with mnemonics to menu "options"
        optionsMenu.add(jmiLogin = new JMenuItem("Login", 'L'));
        optionsMenu.addSeparator();
        optionsMenu.add(jmiBack = new JMenuItem("Back", 'B'));

        //panel p1 to holds text fields
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Username"));
        p1.add(jtfUsername = new JTextField(15));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Password"));
        p1.add(jtfPassword = new JPasswordField(15));

        //panel p2 to holds buttons
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p2.add(backButton = new JButton("Back"));
        p2.add(loginButton = new JButton("Login"));

        //Panel with image??????

        //add panels to frame
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        panel.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setTitle("Main Page");


        //listners for exit menuitem and button
        jmiBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
                welcome.setVisible(true);
                welcome.setSize(500, 500);
                welcome.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                NewClass.this.dispose();
                NewClass.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
                welcome.setVisible(true);
                welcome.setSize(500, 500);
                welcome.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                NewClass.this.dispose();
                NewClass.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        //listner for about menuitem
        jmiAbout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "This is the login panel"
                        + "\n Assignment for University",
                        "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        //action listeners for Login in button and menu item
        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    usernamecheck.checkLogin(jtfUsername.getText(), jtfPassword.getText()); {
                    System.out.println("User is validated");
               }
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                }
                MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu();
                mainmenu.setVisible(true);
                mainmenu.setSize(500, 500);
                mainmenu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                NewClass.this.dispose();
                NewClass.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        jmiLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu();
                mainmenu.setVisible(true);
                mainmenu.setSize(500, 500);
                mainmenu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                NewClass.this.dispose();
                NewClass.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        log frame = new log();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class usernamecheck {

    static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    static final String USERNAME = "root";
    static final String PASSWORD = "root";

   // launch the application
    public static boolean checkLogin(String username, String password)
            throws SQLException {
        System.out.print("dfdF");

        Connection connection = null; // manages connection
        PreparedStatement pt = null; // manages prepared statement

        // connect to database usernames and query database
```

try {

```
        // establish connection to database
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "root", "root");

        // query database
        pt = con.prepareStatement("select userName,password from test.person where userName=?");

        // process query results
        pt.setString(1, username);
        ResultSet rs = pt.executeQuery();
        String orgUname = "", orPass = "";
        while (rs.next()) {
            orgUname = rs.getString("userName");
            orPass = rs.getString("password");
        } //end while
        if (orPass.equals(password)) {
            //do something
            return true;
        } else {
            //do something
        }
    }//end try
    catch (Exception e) {
    } //end catch  
    return false;
} //end main
```

}

Comment: JDBC doesn't check usernames or passwords. It just passes them to the database. Don't vandalize your posts. If the code is confidential, delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `return` type in your `checkLogin` method. You may return a `boolean` value to validate the user. Also add some logging/sysout to make sure what is happening in your code.

Update your method as :

```
// launch the application
    public static boolean checkLogin(String username, String password)
            throws SQLException {
        System.out.print("dfdF");

        Connection connection = null; // manages connection
        PreparedStatement pt = null; // manages prepared statement

        // connect to database usernames and query database
        try {

            // establish connection to database
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "root", "root");

            // query database
            pt = con.prepareStatement("select userName,password from test.person where userName=?");

            // process query results
            pt.setString(1, username);
            ResultSet rs = pt.executeQuery();
            String orgUname = "", orPass = "";
            while (rs.next()) {
                orgUname = rs.getString("userName");
                orPass = rs.getString("password");
            } //end while
            if (orPass.equals(password)) {
                //do something
                return true;
                rs.close();
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        }//end try
        catch (Exception e) {
        } //end catch  
        return false;
    } //end main
```

And then update your user check as

```
           try {
                if(usernamecheck.checkLogin(jtfUsername.getText(), jtfPassword.getText())) {
                    System.out.println("User is validated");
               } else {
                 return;
               }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
            }
```

Comment: Would i write that in the `if (orPass.equals(password)) {` statement?

Comment: @Hayde check updated answer....i have not compiled it so remove any error if it comes.

Comment: I fix the errors, but its still not working :/ I have in my database a username test and password 1234 when i put it in it lets me in, but even when i put random information it also still lets me in. Updated main post

Comment: @Hayde You need to place the if check as mentioned in my answer. And also you need to update an else, as i have mentioned in my updated answer. Put the code that you want to execute when user is not validated, i have put simply a return to return from the method.

Comment: If the user has inputed an incorrect username i'd like it to say invalid user name please try again and deny access, would i just add that to `else { //do something }`

Answer (score 0):

Make your `checkLogin` method return boolean type and return true inside `if (orPass.equals(password)) {` block. Check whether the method true if so grant access.